# pyodbc fast_executemany on Linux garbles strings on insert

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc, executemany

I have the following code, which works fine on Windows, and fails on Linux:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(p_str = None, server = ..., app = ..., databsae = ...,
                      driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
                      Trusted_Connection = 'yes')

conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding = 'utf-8')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding = 'utf-8')
conn.setencoding(encoding = 'utf-8')

sql = 'INSERT INTO TestStrTbl(idKey,idValue) VALUES (?,?)'
data = [('one', 'value1'), ('two', 'value2')]

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.connection.autocommit = False
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
cursor.commit()
```

I am inserting into and empty SQL Server table, created with the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE TestStrTbl
(
    idKey   varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    idValue varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
```

The error returned is:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__TestStrT__3FBEE7404FA9AB3B'.
> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TestStrTbl'. The duplicate
> key value is (?).

When I use the same connection to read, or insert using complete strings, like

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TestStrTbl(idKey,idValue) VALUES ('%s','%s')"
cursor.connection.autocommit = False
cursor.fast_executemany = True
for row in data:
    cursor.execute(sql % row)
cursor.commit()
```

this works just fine. Another possibility is to let `cursor.fast_executemany = False`, then it will work on Linux as well. What could I do to fix this?

I am running Python 3.7.8 with `pyodbc==4.0.24` on Ubuntu Linux.
Thanks for your help.

---

**UPDATE**

Here are the unixODBC settings:

```
18:48:56 $> odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/myUserId/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Comment: According to the error message, `?` is being passed as a literal string, instead of being replaced with the parameter value. This is the layer just above the ODBC driver that's screwing up, because T-SQL does not accept `?` without quotation marks, so you have to really work to get this wrong. To see if this theory is correct, try this with only a single row of data (`[('one', 'value1')]` -- you should end up with a literal `?` in your row. Alternatively, if the problem is an encoding issue, you should still get a value in the row that tells you what's going wrong.

Comment: Also, SQL Server prior to 2019 has no support for UTF-8, and even then only with special collations used for the fields. All Unicode strings in SQL Server are UTF-16. I know almost nothing about `pyodbc`, but I'd be surprised if those `setdecoding`/`setencoding` calls are necessary and/or correct. Samples provided by Microsoft don't seem to include them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert hwat bothers me to no end is that everything works in all cases except Linux with fast executemany. Windows (in either mode) or Linux with fast executemany set to False works like a charm. I also tried with `latin` instead of `utf-8` and it had the same results.

Comment: You definitely need to get rid of the `conn.setdecoding` and `conn.setencoding` statements. SQL Server ODBC does not use UTF-8 encoding. (It uses UTF-16LE, which is the pyodbc default.) Also, run `odbcinst -j` from a terminal prompt to check your version of unixODBC and consider upgrading it if it is old.

Comment: @GordThompson thank you. I updated the question (on the bottom) with the unixODBC settings, do I need to upgrade from that?

Comment: @GordThompson removing the encoding altogether seems to have worked, thank you. I am happy to accept an answer if you write it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call `conn.setdecoding` and `conn.setencoding` when working with Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server. The default encoding for pyodbc is UTF16-LE, which is what Microsoft's ODBC drivers use.

As for [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/), anything prior to version 2.3.5 (2018-01-02) should be considered "old" as that was a major bugfix release. Version 2.3.7 (2018-08-10) fixed several more bugs and is currently the recommended version.

Comment: We found that some of our `SELECT` queries ran _significantly_ faster when the encoding was set to `UTF-8`. It appeared that this was because `pyodbc` was sending the parameters as `NVARCHAR`, whereas the tables defined the columns as `VARCHAR`. Consequently, MSSQL was producing suboptimal query execution plans.

I was hoping that the `UTF-8` encoding would provide a similar performance boost to our `INSERT` queries; unfortunately, we encountered the same `PRIMARY KEY` violation that was mentioned in the question. (due to the use of `fast_executemany`)